# Laravel objeto null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7

Tengo un modelo y controlador de Categorías, donde un método destroy recibo el objeto, pero al mandarlo desde la vista (blade laravel), en el controlador recibo vacío el objeto. ¿Cual podría ser el problema?. La verdad no entiendo ya que tengo otra tabla donde hago el CRUD y no obtuve problemas, el código es casi igual pero cuando hago los cambios no funciona correctamente. El problema pasa lo mismo para los metodos edit y show.

Código controller destroy:

```
public function destroy(CategoryWork $categoryWork)
    {
        dd($categoryWork);
    }
```

Ruta:

```
//Categorias WorkTaller
Route::resource('categorywork','CategoryWorkController')->names('categorieswork');
```

Vista:

```
<tbody>
                           @foreach ($categorieswork as $category)
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">{{$category->id}}</th>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="{{route('categorieswork.show',$category)}}">{{$category->name}}</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{$category->description}}</td>
                                    <td style="width: 50px;">
                                        {!! Form::open(['route'=>['categorieswork.destroy',$category], 'method'=>'DELETE']) !!}

                                    


                                        <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{route('categorieswork.edit', $category->id)}}" style="height:35px;width:50px" title="Editar">
                                            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt btn-icon-append icon_edit"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        
                                        <button class="btn btn-danger eliminar " style="height:35px;width:50px" href="{{route('categorieswork.destroy', $category->id)}}" type="submit" title="Eliminar">
                                            <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                        </button>

                                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach

                            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes listar tus rutas, y veras como se llama el parametro.

```
artisan route:list | grep category
```

Vas a tener un resultado de las rutas que contengan `category`, y al observar la ruta `DELETE`

`|        | DELETE    | api/categorywork/{categorywork} ...`

Date cuenta de define el parametro todo en minuscula `categorywork`, por lo que el nombre del parametro que reciba tu función debe de quedar de la siguiente forma.

```
public function destroy(CategoryWork $categorywork)
{
    dd($categorywork);
}
```

con eso podría funcionar correctamente.

Para no cambiar el controlador, tendrías que definir tu ruta como

`Route::resource('categoryWork', 'CategoryWorkController')->names('categorieswork');`

Comment: Excelente amigo esa fue la solución! Muchas gracias.